# Inserting primary contact in contact provider

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app, i am accessing all the contact from contact db. There are some  scenario where multiple contact numbers are there for a particular contact name .
    I want that when the user select any contact number from that multiple contacts, i will store it in the contact database as primary contact for that contatc_ID . For that i need an empty column in the contact db .
    Can anyone guide me that how i will find an empty column and how to insert data in that empty column in contactContract .

Comment: I am not finding where to start . Its like inserting an email address for a particular contact. I have the contact_ID .

Comment: I think you want to mark a number as the primary phone number, just mark the number as IS_PRIMARY and IS_SUPER_PRIMARY. If you want to use the empty column check the documentation for Data table.